# Equals and hashCode contract with EqualsVerifier

Tags: java, equals, hashcode, final, equalsverifier

I have some doubts about `equals` and `hashCode` contract in Java using [EqualsVerifier](https://code.google.com/p/equalsverifier/) library.

Imagine we have something like this

```
public abstract class Person {

    protected String name;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // only name is taken into account
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // only name is taken into account
    }

}
```

And the following extended class:

```
public final class Worker extends Person {

    private String workDescription;

    @Override
    public final boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // name and workDescription are taken into account
    }

    @Override
    public final int hashCode() {
        // name and workDescription are taken into account
    }

}
```

I try to test whether I fulfill the `equals` and `hashCode` contract in the **Person** class, using [EqualsVerifier](https://code.google.com/p/equalsverifier/)

```
    @Test
    public void testEqualsAndHashCodeContract() {
        EqualsVerifier.forClass(Person.class).verify();
    }
```

Running this test, I get that I have to declare `equals` and `hashCode` methods final, but this is something that I don't want to do, because I may want to declare these two methods in the extended classes, since I want to use some child's attributes in `equals` and `hashCode`.

Could you skip for testing the final rule in the EqualsVerifier library? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the creator of EqualsVerifier. I only just discovered this question :).

The workaround Joachim Sauer mentions is correct.

Let me explain why EqualsVerifier does not like your implementation. Let's pretend for now that `Person` is not abstract; it makes the examples a bit simpler. Let's say we have two `Person` objects, like this:

```
Person person1 = new Person("John");
Person person2 = new Worker("John", "CEO of the world");
```

And let's call `equals` on both these objects:

```
boolean b1 = person1.equals(person2); // returns true
boolean b2 = person2.equals(person1); // returns false
```

`b1` is true, because `Person`'s `equals` method is called, and it ignores `workDescription`. `b2` is false, because `Worker`'s `equals` method is called, and the `instanceof` or `getClass()` check in that method returns false.

In other words, your `equals` method is no longer symmetric, and this is a requirement for a correct implementation of `equals`, according to [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

You can indeed use `getClass()` to get around this problem, but then you run into another problem. Let's say you use Hibernate, or a mocking framework. These frameworks use bytecode manipulation to create subclasses of your class. Essentially, you'll get a class like this:

```
class Person$Proxy extends Person { }
```

So let's say you make a round trip to the database, like this:

```
Person person1 = new Person("John");
em.persist(person1);
// ...
Person fetchedPerson = em.find(Person.class, "John");
```

And now let's call `equals`:

```
boolean b3 = person1.equals(fetchedPerson); // returns false
boolean b4 = fetchedPerson.equals(person1); // also returns false
```

`b3` and `b4` are false because `person1` and `fetchedPerson` are of different classes (`Person` and `Person$Proxy`, to be precise). `equals` is symmetric now, so at least it follows the contract, but it's still not what you want: `fetchedPerson` doesn't "behave" like a `Person` anymore. In technical terms: this breaks the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which is the basis for Object-Oriented Programming.

There is a way to make all this work, but it's quite complicated. (If you really want to know: [this article](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html) explains how.) To keep things simple, EqualsVerifier suggests that you make your `equals` and `hashCode` methods final. In most cases, this will work fine. If you really need to, you can always take the complicated route.

In your case, since `Person` is abstract, you could also choose to not implement `equals` in `Person`, but only in `Worker` (and any other subclasses you may have).

Comment: Next time, I'll try not to wait a year before responding :).

Answer (score 5):

Getting that right is very tricky.

[The documentation of EqualsVerifier](http://jqno.nl/equalsverifier/errormessages/subclass-equals-is-not-final/) explains a workaround:

```
EqualsVerifier.forClass(MyClass.class)
    .withRedefinedSubclass(SomeSubclass.class)
    .verify();
```

Note that for this to work, you probably need to check `getClass()` in your equals because a `Worker` can (or should) never be equal to a `Person`.